# How to set opacity in parent div and not affect in child div?

Tags: css, parent-child, opacity

Hey i am searching in google but i can't fine any perfect answer

I want to Opacity in parent DIV but not Child  DIV

Example

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">
Hello I am child 
</div>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
.parent{
background:url('../images/madu.jpg') no-repeat 0 0;
}
.child{
Color:black;
}
```

**Note: --** I want to **background-image** in `Parent Div` not Color

Comment: hey  @DavidThomas  How can u say this question is Duplicate if you have any answer related in this questions wiout used Position and used to Background-images in parent div in pure css .............

Comment: Pre-edit it seemed to be; I read the question in mobile and then, to find duplicates, I switched to desktop. I didn't re-read your question between times. My close-vote will fade away, though, so don't worry about it.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

May be it's good if you define your **background-image** in the `:after` pseudo class. Write like this:

```
.parent{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.parent:after{
    content:'';
    background:url('http://www.dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff&text=parent+image');
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    opacity:0.5;
}
.child{
    background:yellow;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hzSG8/)

Comment: my answer is quite similar to yours, but i can't imageine what's wrong with mine

Comment: @sandeep thanks for the exact answer we were totally confused in this bug......thanks buddy......

Comment: @VladimirStarkov when i give my answer i didn't saw your answer :)

Comment: Use `background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);` instead of opacity. It will not inheritance.

Comment: As @AshwinP said, his answer worked for me

Comment: Your .parent:after  `opacity` is not work. Change/remove your background then its clear...!!!

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hzSG8/1249/)

Comment: is this possible with background-color instead of a background-image? I can't get it working with background-color

Comment: @AshwinP Thanks your solutions seems to be exact.

Comment: This answer is bad for 2 obvious reasons - you should set transparancy like @AshwinP said. But also, because if you place it in the :after pseudo class you are essentially creating a transparant box on top of your content, not under it. If the answer was to place it in :before instead - fine, that could be a solution. But this is just wrong.

Comment: Ashwin Parmar answer is the correct and the most suitable for this case,

Comment: @AshwinParmar this is what I needed for mine. I was doing a background linear gradient and using a separate opacity. Instead, I switched each rgba alpha value and it did not inherit.

Answer (score 121):

I know this is old, but just in case it will help someone else.

```
<div style="background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)">child</div>
```

Where `rgba` is: red, green, blue, and `a` is for transparency.

Comment: ...aaand it does not affect other background colors within the child div's (just a quick note)

Comment: Adding an hard-coded inline-style is wrong, Please don't share this.

Comment: but OP has background-image, it doesnt work there

Comment: Most times inline styling is frowned upon, but in some production contexts it can still be used. Anyway point is `background-color: rgba(...)` is the way to do it.  So this was still helpful

Answer (score 20):

You **can do it** with pseudo-elements: ([demo on dabblet.com](http://dabblet.com/gist/2867543))
[image]

**your markup:**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"> Hello I am child </div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.parent{
    position: relative;
}

.parent:before {
    z-index: -1;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;

    opacity: 0.2;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background: url('http://img42.imageshack.us/img42/1893/96c75664f7e94f9198ad113.png') no-repeat 0 0; 
}

.child{
    Color:black;
}
```

Comment: hey @Vlamimir starkov i don't used position ...............

Comment: @RohitAzad why it is so big deal?

Comment: +1 for your answer you were also near about my requirement actually you didn't define the width height in your parent so that's why i was bit confused in your anwers byw thanks.......

Comment: @RohitAzad i defined it only for pseudo element for more flexibility

Answer (score 14):

As mentioned by Tom, `background-color: rgba(229,229,229, 0.85)` can do the trick.
Place that on the style of the parent element and child wont be affected.

Answer (score 6):

You can't. Css today simply doesn't allow that.

The logical rendering model is this one :

> If the object is a container element, then the effect is as if the contents of the container element were blended against the current background using a mask where the value of each pixel of the mask is .

Reference : [css transparency](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparency)

The solution is to use a different element composition, usually using fixed or computed positions for what is today defined as a child : it may appear logically and visualy for the user as a child but the element doesn't need to be really a child in your code.

A solution using css : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/RVppt/)

```
.parent {
    width:500px;
    height:200px;    
    background-image:url('http://canop.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/cropped-bandeau-cr%C3%AAte-011.jpg');
    opacity: 0.2;
}
.child {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
}
```

Another solution with javascript : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/WnQJ9/)

Comment: Thanks but this is only background color related not background images .............

Comment: can u give me some example on jsfiddle.net

Comment: hi Thank for make a jsfiddle but i don't used position .......

Comment: You'll have to define the position of the "child" (that isn't really a child). Either with javascript or with css. There may be a lot of solutions, each one adapted to a specific web composition.

Comment: I added another fiddle : in this one you don't have to know the position of the false child when making the css file.

Comment: I'm upvoting this because I've returned to this question several times, and each time I abandon the highest ranking solutions. Sure, they work, but every time, I end up using a 1px PNG background. I've done it like 5 times now.  So, yes, as this answer says, it looks like CSS isn't too good at this. Hopefully I'll find this comment next time I'm considering this.

Comment: This is wrong. The child has to be inside the parent, which is not in the Fiddle example

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I fixed by setting transparent png image as background for the parent tag.

[This is the 1px x 1px PNG Image that I have created with 60% Opacity of black background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eS18.png) !

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, unless you take the child out of the parent and place it via positioning.

The only way I know and it actually works, is to **use a translucid image** (.png with transparency) for the parent's background. The only disavantage is that you can't control the opacity via CSS, other than that it works!