# How do I handle independent parent and child opacities when the child element is a link?

Tags: html, css, opacity

I have a parent `<div>` and a child `<a>`. The parent has a background image set to 60% opacity, but I'd like the child link to have 100% opacity. My reason for implementing it this way is so I can fade the parent's opacity to 100% on hover, thereby eliminating the need for a hover image.

I understand that children inherit their parent's opacity. I tried the `:after {}` technique described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879045/how-to-set-opacity-in-parent-div-and-not-effect-in-child-div), but even with appropriate `z-index` values set, the child link still sits beneath the parent element and is not clickable.

**My issue is that the child link cannot be clicked because the parent's `:after` pseudo-element sits above the child.**

My code is as follows:

```
<div>
  <a href="#">Load more</a>
</div>

div {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
} 
div:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  background: url('../img/bg-load-more.png') repeat-x;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
div a {
  display: block;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Does anyone know of a solution to this issue, or must I create an image sprite and switch swap background images on hover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't applying a position to the `<a>` itself (z-index only applies to [`positioned elements)`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-z-index) only the containing div and the pseudo-element, so the pseudo-element is sitting on top of the link preventing it from being clicked.

All you need to do is give the link a stacking context, e.g. include relative positioning:

```
div a {
display: block;
position: relative;
z-index: 100;
}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/TDH4x/)

Comment: Stacking context, got it. Your solution works perfectly. Thanks!