# how to change only one item in a class

Tags: html, css

I just want the background image's opacity to be changed. Not the whole items like p.
css:

```
#home{
background-image: url('../img/main.jpg');
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: relative;
height:100%;
opacity: .8;
}
```

html:

```
<section id="home">
   <p>hi</p>
   <p>hi</p>
   <p>hi</p>
   <p>hi</p>
   <p>hi</p>
 </section>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879045/how-to-set-opacity-in-parent-div-and-not-affect-in-child-div

Comment: @jonathanmcdaniel No, that's not the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule `opacity` is for the element. Not for the `background`. If you need to do that way, you have two options:

1. Fake the background by using another `div` and use `opacity` on it.
2. Use two different images with one having lesser `opacity`.

There are a lot of hacks available:

- [CSS Opacity on Child Element](http://www.impressivewebs.com/demo-files/css-opacity/)
- Using `:after` and styling it.

Answer (score 0):

while there isnt any way to change the background opacity directly, there is hacky way of doing it.

```
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

div::after {
  content: "";
  background: url(image.jpg);
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;   
}
```

[taken from here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/transparent-background-images/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any property for CSS background transparency.

What you could do is create a child element that fills the space, and apply the background and transparency to that element.

If you want to pure CSS solution, you can create the child element using the :before pseudo selector with an empty content field.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only wanting to change the opacity of a background image, it may be easier to actually save the image with a lower opacity, to avoid writing extra markup.

However, there are hacky work arounds that involve moving the 'child' elements over the top of the background using absolute positioning - there's a really useful article [here](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-opacity-that-doesnt-affect-child-elements/).