# How to make a child div transparent?

Tags: html, css, nested, transparency

Suppose there is a div, say "*parent-div*". 
The parent div has a background color. What if the child div, "*child-div*", needs to be set with a transparent background,such that it is set with the background image of the grandparent div, with class name "*wrapper*"?

I know that a child div can inherit css properties from parent div, but how do I set the background to transparent, making the whole picture appear like the parent-div has a hole in it?

```css
.wrapper{
  background-image: url('http://media.istockphoto.com/photos/medium-golden-brown-wood-texture-background-picture-id513694258?k=6&m=513694258&s=170667a&w=0&h=xETakP7VjpAtRj9e6rJRYNqw_AJLZ9ovLlC4ebR5BOQ=');
}

.parent-div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ff0000;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: auto;
}

.child-div{
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="parent-div">
    <div class="child-div">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't apply `background` on `.parent-div`.

Instead use a large value of `box-shadow` on `.child-div` and add `overflow: hidden` on `.parent-div` to hide unwanted shadow effect.

Following css will do the work:

```
.parent-div {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.child-div {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 500px #f00;
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background-image: url('http://media.istockphoto.com/photos/medium-golden-brown-wood-texture-background-picture-id513694258?k=6&m=513694258&s=170667a&w=0&h=xETakP7VjpAtRj9e6rJRYNqw_AJLZ9ovLlC4ebR5BOQ=');
}

.parent-div {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: auto;
}

.child-div {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 500px #f00;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="parent-div">
    <div class="child-div">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hzSG8/)

based on:

```
.parent{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.parent:after{
    content:'';
    background:url('http://www.dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff&text=parent+image');
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    opacity:0.5;
}
.child{
    background:yellow;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```

[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879045/how-to-set-opacity-in-parent-div-and-not-affect-in-child-div)

Comment: No, this isn't what I asked. In the Fiddle you provided, the child div should inherit the body background. Opacity is not the issue for me. This is a solution to display a child div over a parent without inheriting opacity from parent. That's not what I asked.

Comment: The child div should be green, it should appear like it goes through the parent div's color, ignoring it and inheriting the green from its grandparent.

Comment: could you provide some picture for your answer please? It may help

Comment: Reference image has been added.