# preventing a child div from inheriting background from it's parent

Tags: html, css

I want `.child` class background red without setting it directly
or I want it's background transparent so I can see the `.grands` background through it.

I have tried this:

```
<div class="grands">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

style :

```
.grands{
    width: 80vw;
    height: 80vh;
    background-color: red;
}
.parent{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, pink 4%, blue 88%);
}
.child{
    width: 40%;
    height: 40%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 4px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: You can't have the `.child` div effectively create a hole through the `.parent` div to show the contents (ie:red) of the `.grands` div

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52590674/is-a-see-through-child-div-possible

Answer (score -2):

Try these

The `.child.child1` has a red background with 50% opacity, allowing you to see through it.
The `.child.child2` has a transparent background.

Add this in your css file

```
.child.child1 {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Red with 50% opacity */
}

.child.child2 {
    background-color: transparent; /* Transparent background */
}
```

Update HTML File.

```
<div class="grands">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child child1"></div>
        <div class="child child2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```