# CSS animation behavior

Tags: html, css

I got this sample here is it possible to make the inside of the div which is "p" not animate but the div container animates?

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}

div p {
 position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    0%{ opacity:.4;}
 100%{opacity:1;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
    0%{ opacity:.4;}
 100%{opacity:1;}
}
```

```html
<div><p>Sample text here.</p></div>
```

Comment: No, but you could simulate it with a sibbling div to the p, or you could replicate the specifc example in your question with `background-color:transparent` instead of `opacity`, it depends what exactly you want to accomplish.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set opacity in parent div and not affect in child div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879045/how-to-set-opacity-in-parent-div-and-not-affect-in-child-div)

Comment: What do you mean by simulate it with sibbling div to the p? The background-color:transparent wouldn't accomplish the thing I was aiming for.

Comment: @MarkAnthony Can you select an answer to be the accepted answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The opacity you're changing applies to everything inside that div, so also the children. A way around this is to not change the opacity, but the background only. You can do this by using `rgba()` which includes an `opacity` setting instead of a solid background color like "red".

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
    -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}

div p {
 position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    0%{background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);}
 100%{background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
    0%{background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);}
 100%{background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);}
}
```

```html
<div><p>Sample text here.</p></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I mean by a sibbling div to the p:

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

.animate {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}

div p {
 position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    0%{ opacity:.4;}
 100%{opacity:1;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
    0%{ opacity:.4;}
 100%{opacity:1;}
}
```

```html
<div><div class="animate"></div><p>Sample text here.</p></div>
```

Depending exactly what you are trying to accomplish, this could potentially be done with a `:before` as well.

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

div:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}

div p {
 position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    0%{ opacity:.4;}
 100%{opacity:1;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
    0%{ opacity:.4;}
 100%{opacity:1;}
}
```

```html
<div><p>Sample text here.</p></div>
```