# why cant override the opacity of my MenuItem

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I'm using hakra UI to create an interface and when the project is finished it will have an opacity of 0.5 but I want only the button inside it to have an opacity of 1

I need my MenuItem to have an opacity of 1 while the rest of my project has an opacity of 0.5

```
{projects.map(p => (
<Flex opacity={p.project.status==='CONCLUIDO' ? '0.5' : '1'}>
  <Flex gap='20px'>
    <Flex justifyContent='space-between' width='100%' gap='10px'>
      <Menu>
        <MenuButton </MenuButton>
          <MenuList>
            <MenuItem opacity={ "1"} to={`/projetos?visualizar=${p.project.id}`} as={Link}>Visualizar projeto</MenuItem>
          </MenuList>
      </Menu>
    </Flex>
  </Flex>
```

Comment: Well because thats not the way how css/html works. When you say the Parent has an opacity value of `0.5` the whole container and its children will have that opacity.

Comment: I'm trying some way to override the style

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I do not want to inherit the child opacity from the parent in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770341/i-do-not-want-to-inherit-the-child-opacity-from-the-parent-in-css)

Comment: Or this? [How to set opacity in parent div and not affect in child div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879045/how-to-set-opacity-in-parent-div-and-not-affect-in-child-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I havent found any way to override the opacity. I had to take it out of the container that contains the opacity and create another one